# How to generate code as Eclipse Visual Editor Does

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, eclipse-emf

I want to create an editor which should be drag and drop and it should generate source code accordingly.I found Visual Editor is doing almost the same what I wanted to achieve. I already went through GEF but I was expecting is there any source code available for Visual Editor so that I could understand the code generation logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Visual Editor is now an [Eclipse project](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) you can access the sources from CVS. See here for more details: http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/faq.html#install_cvs

On a side note: [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/) is an other Eclipse project aiming at creating code Generator. I really recommend to have a look at it. If you are not familiar with modeling techniques the learning curve maybe quite long but once you get it it's really powerful.

Comment: Do you know wich technology is used by windowbuilder to generate code ? I tried to study the code but I think I need a lot of time to understand the generation, I just want to know what they have used ?

Comment: No sorry, but I guess they are using GEF somewhere.